# Ruby, Rake, Mysql - creating database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rake

How to do?
I tried something like:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:load
```

in file `/lib/tasks/load_tasks.rake` and this file I tried in terminal as `rake db:migrate`, but I am getting errors about syntax etc.

I entered into terminal this command (I saw it in tutorial):

```
rails generate scaffold Account user_name:string description:text premium:boolean \
      income:integer ranking:float fee:decimal birthday:date login_time:time
```

And this made me file `20110518181941_create_accounts.rb`

How can I create database table - I thought the command above will create me database in mysql... I am now a bit confusing, what to do?

Which rule is playing here `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes, and I am getting error:

http://pastebin.com/xNFmvjZm

But I don't know, what is wrong... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting this error because your syntax is wrong, please put `&&` between sentences:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create && db:schema:load
```

or do it in separated lines

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load
```

the first command will create the database, the second command will Load the `db/schema.rb` file into the database

And finally you need to run your migration:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

to create your Accounts table.

BTW if you run:

```
rake -T
```

you can see the list of rake tasks and their descriptions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply JCorcuera. I tried to edit my code under your hints, but I am getting error about syntax - http://pastebin.com/2gyd6NNH. The arrow show the place, where is problem - I copied the error from terminal

Comment: I think you are doing db:load but is db:schema:load; and the commandi is rake -T not -t

Comment: @user705586: You're supposed to run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create` and `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load` from the shell command line, your error looks like you have them in a `.rake` file.

Comment: Yes, of course these two lines are in task.rake, I read this commands must be in a file, that have suffix .rake... I am a bit confused - what is right?

Well, I would like to ask you how to run these two commands from terminal... I am newbie. Thanks in advance!